"istRT: Volume Full" error permanent handling
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04. However, after each rebooting I face the following error:
istRT: Volume Full
Could not creat MokListXRT: Volume Full
Could not create SbatLevelRT: Volume Full
could not creaste MokListTrustedRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import mok_state() failed: Volume Full

In order to be able to boot I try deleting Forbidden signatures. Although it works, but I have to do this trick whenever I restart my laptop. Is there any way to remedy this issue permanently?
